# How do I make a child theme's style.css load after plugin css?

Tags: css

A client website is using Ultimate Visual Composer Addons plugin, which load its CSS file after the parent and child theme stylesheets.

How do I load the child theme stylesheet after the Ultimate Visual Composer Addons stylesheet?

Help appreciated.

**Update**: from @the_dramatist's answer, I've created a `functions.php` in the child theme, and added:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ross_north_child_theme_scripts' );
function ross_north_child_theme_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'houzez-style-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'houzez-style-css', 'http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au/wp-content/themes/houzez-child/style.css', array('ultimate-style-min-css' ), null, 'all' );
}
```

but `ultimate-style-min-css` is still loading after `houzez-style-css` at [this site](http://rossnorth.websitetechnology.com.au).

Comment: Have you tried setting the priority like `wp_enqueue_scripts('script','function',10,3)` ?

Comment: I've two questions, 1) How you wanna do it ? through a custom plugin or you've access to the themes `functions.php` And 2) Have you found out the handles of **Visual Composer Addons stylesheet** ? If not then find them first.

Comment: Thanks @the_dramatist. 1) I have access to `functions.php`, and 2) the handle is `ultimate-style-min-css`. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, currently two different ways are coming to my head-

One way could be, using `ultimate-style-min-css` as a dependency of your child theme `style.css`-

```
/**
 * Say this below function is your theme enqueue
 */
function the_dramatist_child_theme_scripts(){
    wp_enqueue_style ('your-child-theme-css','YOUR CSS URL HERE', array( 'ultimate-style-min-css' ), null, 'all');
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','the_dramatist_child_theme_scripts');
```

Another would be using `wp_dequeue_style` first then enqueue the child theme style with `ultimate-style-min-css` as a dependency-

```
/**
 * Here we first dequeue the style and then we'll enqueue the child theme style again with ultimate-style-min-css as a dependency.
 */
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ross_north_child_theme_scripts' );
function ross_north_child_theme_scripts() {
    wp_dequeue_style( 'houzez-style-css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'houzez-style-css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', array('ultimate-style-min-css' ), null, 'all' );
}
```

> An update after the question has been updated.

Last way in my mind is, that if your child theme stylesheet is being enqueued at `wp_head` with a lower priority than your plugins stylesheet's priority then the solution would be to use the same `wp_head` hook, with a *lower* priority for your plugin stylesheet.

Hope the above helps.

Comment: Thanks. The first answer probably won't work, as the child theme is not enqueuing its `style.css` in `functions.php`. I've updated my question with a note about the 2nd method.

Comment: Try the updated code. @Steve

Comment: Check if child theme is activated or not. Then clear cache and try again. Cause I just checked your site and has not found any `houzez-style-css`.

Comment: Child theme is activated. I see `houzez-style-css` when logged in as admin, but not when logged out. Site used to have WP Rocket activated, but that is now deactivated. Cleared browser cache and `houzez-style-css` still not present when logged out. No caching plugins active. Potentially it is server caching.

Comment: I reactivated WP Rocket, but turned caching off. `houzez-style-css` is now present for logged off users.

Comment: Is in the admin the css enqueued right way ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to tell. In admin view source, I see plugin CSS and theme admin CSS. They look fine and normal.

Comment: Hello? Can you still provide some assistance please TD?

Comment: Sure... But the description you've given is not enough to debug this. Better you try deactivating each plugin and see what happens then. Then post here the result.